# content-id format

Tags: email

I have my mail reading application in jsp which display's an email message. I am trying to display a mail which is having images embedded in it. However i am not able to see images contained inside mail. I can see images when i open the mail in thunderbird.

When i opened mail message i saw that content-id was not present withing angular braces.

example

```
<img src="cid:Logo.gif"..>
```

corresponding content was like follows

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=Logo.gif
Content-ID: Logo.gif

R0lGODlhswA1APcAAOsKHCY0bug........
```

So here , if i replace line `Content-ID: Logo.gif` with `Content-ID: <Logo.gif>`, I am able to view images.

As per RFC (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2392.txt), i found that content-id  is enclosed in angle brackets (<>). but on wikipedia, I found that this is not mandatory.

Anyone knows what's the correct format of content id ?

Comment: Not everyone follows the spec.  And when this happens it encourages incorrect behavior.  See `IE6` for example.

Answer (score 2):

The correct format of the content id is enclosed in angle brackets as per RFC.

But the Web URI is without the angle brackets.